# Replace multiple GoTo by a loop in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets

/!\ ON GOOGLE APPS SCRIPT /!\

I need an example to replace the existing GoTo statements in VBA with switch or while loop etc.

For the moment, I managed to understand a little bit the principle of GoTo on this example:

VBA INSTRUCTIONS :

```
date_deb:
    lig = lig + 1
    If Cells(lig, cc).Value = Cells(lig - 1, cc).Value And _
        Cells(lig, cc).Value <> "" Then GoTo date_deb
```

GAS INSTRUCTION (Google Apps Script):

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("GoTo");
  var lig = 2;
  var cc = 9;
  var temp = ss.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  date_deb:while(true){
    lig++;
    if(temp[lig][cc-1] == temp[lig-1][cc-1] && temp[lig][cc-1] !=""){
      continue date_deb;
    }
    break;
  }
```

These instructions allow me to increment the lig variable by 1 each time I find the same value in column 9.

Now let's imagine that I add a new GoTo statement in VBA.

VBA INSTRUCTIONS :

```
date_deb:
    lig = lig + 1
    If Cells(lig, cc).Value = Cells(lig - 1, cc).Value And _
        Cells(lig, cc).Value <> "" Then GoTo date_deb
    Rows("2:" & lig - 1).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
chg_sem:
    lig = 2
    day = Cells(lig, cc).Value
    week = CInt(Format(day, "ww", vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays))
date_eq:
    lig = lig + 1
    If Cells(lig, cc).Value = Cells(lig - 1, cc).Value And _
        Cells(lig, cc).Value <> "" Then GoTo date_eq
    If Cells(lig, cc).Value <> "" Then
        If week = CInt(Format(Cells(lig, cc).Value, "ww", vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)) _
            Then GoTo date_eq
    End If
    lig2 = lig - 1
```

Instinctively, I'll tell myself that in GAS, I should do :

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("GoTo");
  var lig = 2;
  var cc = 9;
  var temp = ss.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  date_deb:while(true){
    lig++;
    if(temp[lig][cc-1] == temp[lig-1][cc-1] && temp[lig][cc-1] !=""){
      continue date_deb;
    }
    break;
  }
  chg_sem:while(true){
    lig = 2;
    day = temp[lig-1][cc-1];
    week = [Using of FORMULA weekday etc.].
    break;
  }

date_eq: while(true){
      lig ++;
      if(temp[lig][cc-1] == temp[lig-1][cc-1] && temp[lig][cc-1] != ""){
         continue date_eq;
      }
      if[...]{
        continue date_eq;
      }
     break
}
```

For example, if in the next part of my program I need to reuse the chg_sem:while(true) loop (or another one) how should I proceed in Google Apps Script?

What I mean is that the GoTo in VBA can be used anywhere in the program, so what about in Google Apps Script?

EDIT :

As Marti said, I was on the wrong way to solve my issue, so I'm actually trying with this :

```
function date_deb(lig,cc){

    var file= "file";
    var fichier_loc;
      var feuille1_loc;

    var lig = lig;
    var cc = cc;

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var s2 = ss.getSheets()[2];

    var temp;

    const r_local = "Local_Temp";
    const r_logis = "flux";

    fichier_loc = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(r_local).next().getFilesByName(file).next();

    temp = fichier_loc.getId();

    fichier_loc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(temp);

    feuille1_loc = fichier_loc.getSheets()[0];

    temp = feuille1_loc.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
    
    date_deb: while(true){
      lig++;
      if(temp[lig][cc-1] == temp[lig-1][cc-1] && temp[lig-1][cc-1]){
        continue date_deb;
      }
      break;
    }

    return lig;
}
```

I know that it's not the best mean, if you have got something easier to reach my goal, I would appreciate that.

Comment: The best way is probably to not literally translate, but implement with another paradigm. What does your code do?

Comment: All right, so I'm new in coding, I used not to see "GoTo" instructions so I'm trying to shuffle my mind in order to get another way to replace it. Atm I did this :

Removed literraly translation because I knew that was the wrong way to deal with (hence my request for a concrete example ); 

I just code another function that I call in my program which allow me to "refer" this equivalent of a "GoTo" instruction everywhere in my program.

Comment: I just updated my Question to share the code I did

Comment: Could you give a bit more context on what the script should do? I'm not asking for the code, I'm asking about the result you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This is a macro that has the purpose of making a history of data tracking files. According to the days of the week and the number of the week. This macro is weekly, it allows to increment data. 

For example, the file W01 corresponds to the first week of the year. Currently we are in the 36th week, the last file W36 corresponds to the 36th week of the year 2020, so after the execution of the macro last Monday, the file of 2020 has been replaced by that of this year.

Comment: Try to avoid GoTo in VBA. It makes for spaghetti code. In your example above you could simply have used While Loops and a combination of And / Or statements within a single IF.

Comment: So you are grabbing all the data and moving it into another file?

Comment: I'm copying data, and I add columns on this file

Comment: Would you consider providing a copy of the spreadsheet (free of sensitive information) in order to clarify the desired goal?